# pandas : drop duplicates in the same time when grouping by

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

im doing a simple groupby on my data as shown in the code below. Is there a manner to do it directly without the drop_duplicates please, in the same line of code?

Thank you

```
 df_brut['Revenue'] = df_brut.groupby(['cod', 'date', 'zone'])['Revenue'].transform('sum')
 df_brut = df_brut.drop_duplicates()
 df_brut.columns = ['cod','date', 'zone','SUM_']
```

My data

```
data1 = {'date': ['2021-06', '2021-06', '2021-07', '2021-07', '2021-07', '2021-07'], 'cod': ['12', '12', '14', '15', '15', '18'], 'zone': ['LA', 'LA', 'LA', 'PARIS', 'PARIS', 'PARIS'], 'Revenue': [10, 20, 30, 50, 40, 10]}  
df_brut= pd.DataFrame(data1)
```

the grouped data expected is

```
data2 = {'date': ['2021-06', '2021-07', '2021-07', '2021-07'], 'cod': ['12', '14', '15','18'], 'zone': ['LA', 'LA', 'PARIS', 'PARIS'], 'SUM_': [30, 30, 90, 10]}  
df_grouped= pd.DataFrame(data2)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

```
(df_brut.groupby(['cod', 'date', 'zone'], as_index=False)['Revenue']
        .sum()
        .rename({'Revenue': '_SUM'}, axis=1)
)
```

Comment: Ok thank you @Arkadiusz do you know why im gotting the duplicate rows please?

Comment: You get duplicate rows because you use 'transform' which keeps an original shape of a dataframe. When you don't use it, you see only groups, without duplicates. Please look at some examples of 'transform' function in the documentation. After that do the same for 'groupby'.